# Scrubbing files from the shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

My shell skills are a bit rusty, but what I am trying to do is take 2 files and 'scrub' one from the other based on a matching field.  That's the important part the rest of the line can be different, but if the key field matches up it will be removed. For example my files are pipe delimited and the second field is the key field.

```
File 1
------
acme|widg001|green|plant a|<timestamp>
acme|widg102|blue|plant b|<timestamp>
acme|widg002|yellow|plant a|<timestamp

File 2
------
acme|widg001|blue|plant a|<timestamp>
acme|widg701|blue|plant a|<timestamp>
```

When I scrub File 2 from File 1 what I want the resulting file to contain is

```
New File
------
acme|widg102|blue|plant b|<timestamp>
acme|widg002|yellow|plant a|<timestamp>
```

Ideally the solution would allow me to specify more than 2 files ie Scrub files 2, 3 & 4 from file 1.

Any assistance would be great!

Comment: I don't understand the operation.  What is the matching field in your example?

Comment: He wants File 1 NOT File 1 based on `widg###`, it seems.

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for Bash I decided to give it a go using only Bash.  No external programs at all.

```
IFS='|'
declare -A scrub

while read f1 f2 rest; do
    scrub[$f2]=0
done < file2.txt

while read f1 f2 rest; do
    if [ ! ${scrub[$f2]} ]; then
        echo "$f1|$f2|$rest"
    fi
done < file1.txt
```

This caches the values to scrub first, then iterates through the candidates from the first file, printing those that are not scrubbed.  It's not pretty, but it's Bash.

Comment: +1 for the effort and it's relatively elegant using bash 4's associative arrays

Answer (score 1):

this awk one liner could work multiple files as argument: **(file1 must be the last)**

```
 awk -F'|' 'ARGIND<ARGC-1{a[$2];next} !($2 in a)' fileN fileN-1..... file1
```

The key is the usage of `ARGC and ARGIND` variables of awk.

test with 3 files

```
kent$  head f*                                                  
==> f1 <==
acme|widg001|green|plant a|<timestamp>
acme|widg102|blue|plant b|<timestamp>
acme|widg002|yellow|plant a|<timestamp>

==> f2 <==
acme|widg001|blue|plant a|<timestamp>
acme|widg701|blue|plant a|<timestamp>

==> f3 <==
acme|widg102|blue|plant a|<timestamp>
acme|widg701|blue|plant a|<timestamp>

kent$  awk -F'|' 'ARGIND<ARGC-1{a[$2];next} !($2 in a)' f2 f3 f1
acme|widg002|yellow|plant a|<timestamp>
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be close

```
join --check-order -v 1 -t\| -j 2 \
     <(sort -t \| -k2 file1) 
     <(sort -t \| -k2 file2)
```

it prints

```
widg002|acme|yellow|plant a|<timestamp
widg102|acme|blue|plant b|<timestamp>
```

This looks to be spot on, except for the fact

- that output is sorted on the key column, due to the way how `join` expects it's input
- key columns get moved to the front. If you have header columns `--header` will make this a lot clearer.

If you insist on manual column ordering, try a FORMAT specification like:

```
-o "$(echo 1.{1..5})"
```

which prints

```
acme|widg002|yellow|plant a|<timestamp
acme|widg102|blue|plant b|<timestamp>
```

**[`man join`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/join)** and **[`man sort`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sort)**  are your friend for any other tweaks